# counting record of related table with hasMany relationship-laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, orm

I have following table

```
cards
----------

id | name

card_pin
----------
id|card_id|pin
```

i need to pull all cards along with their pin count like below

```
card        no_of_pins
c1            10
c2            20
```

My model

```
class Card extends \Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'cards';


     public function CardPin()    {
        return $this->hasMany('CardPin');
    }
}
```

ORM

```
Card::where('is_active', '=', 'Y')->get();
inside the loop i have to do the following
Card::find(id)->CardPin()
```

Isnt there some effecient way to write ORM which exatly is the replica of

```
SELECT 
card,
(SELECT count(pin) FROM card_pin cp where cp.card_id=cards.id) as no_of_pins
FROM
cards
```